# How to load cached images while use webview.loadData(...) without network

Tags: android, caching, webview

Help me please.

I load html data into `webView` using `loadData(...)`.

This data contains `<img src='http://external.com/some.jpg'/>`

I want this image to be loaded from web if network is available, or to be used from cache if network is unavailable.

I'm not using javascript.
I prefer to use mechanism within webView or android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //First write logic of caching image using 
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(....)
    //Although I do not recommend using above method. Cache image using alternative method. 


    if(check internet connection method)
               + "<img  src=\"http://external.com/some.jpg\">"
    else
                            + "</img>
                            + "<img  src=\"file:///android_asset/some.jpg\">"
                            + "</img>
//android_asset folder if file is shipped with apk or path captured above
```